# Search for odd indices using the section method

Tags: fortran

I don't understand how I can implement the search for even elements using the section method.

I did a search for odd elements, but I need to find even ones

I need it to output `2 4 6 8`, but my program outputs `1 3 5 7 9`

```
program main
  implicit none
  
  integer, DIMENSION(3, 3) :: array = reshape((/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 /), shape(array))
  integer                  :: i = 0
  integer, allocatable     :: B(:)
  
  B = [(Array(::2,i), i=1, 3)]
  print *, B
end program main
```

Comment: Do you need your search to work for arbitrary `array` inputs, or just for the one you've givven?

Comment: Also, your program outputs "1 3 4 6 7 9", not "1 3 5 7 9".

Comment: @veryreverie, For arbitrary inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in the elements with odd indices, you want

```
B = [(Array(modulo(i,2)+1::2, i), i=1, 3)]
```

`modulo(i,2)+1` is `2` when `i` is odd, and `1` when `i` is even. This means that for columns with odd `i` you select every other element starting at the second element, and for columns with even `i` you select every other element starting at the first element.

If instead you're interested in selecting the odd values from an arbitrary array, you can't do this with a simple slice, and you instead need a conditional filter. For example,

```
B = [integer::]
do i=1,3
  do j=1,3
    if (modulo(Array(j,i),2)==0) then
      B = [B, Array(j,i)]
    endif
  enddo
enddo
```

Comment: Some people might prefer `b = pack(array, modulo(array,2)==0)` to pack the even elements of `array` into `b`.